# Highcharts - increment a class name so piechart slices can be uniquely styled in style.css

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am creating a HighCharts pie chart and want finer styling control over each slice -- I want light slices to have dark dataLabels and vice versa.

So, I want to be able to style the slices using my style.css file. I've inserted a class name (slice) in the dataLabels setup, plus a custom function to cycle through all my slices and give them unique classes:

```
function colorSlices(chart) {
                var count = 1;
                $(".slice").each(function(){
                    $(this).addClass("slice-"+count);
                    count++;
                });
};

var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Build the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            credits: { enabled: false },
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                exporting: { enabled: false },                
                events: {
                    redraw: function(event) {
                        colorSlices();
                    }
                },
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                shadow: true
                    },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            legend: {
            useHTML: true,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            itemWidth: 260,
            borderColor: '#fff',
            width: 260,
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<div class="legend-item">' + this.name +'</div>';
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ""
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    size:'100%',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    showInLegend: true,
                    shadow: true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        distance: -40,
                        useHTML: true,
                        style: {
                                width: '100px'
                                },
                        color: '#fff',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<span class="slice">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,1,".",",") +' %</span>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                 name: 'Income Investments',
                data: [
                    ['Other Industries',     19.3],
                    ['Media',   16.0],                                   
                    ['Materials',   13.6],
                    ['Software & Services', 10.2],
                    ['Retailing',    7.9],
                    ['Capital Goods',     6.5],
                    ['Healthcare Equipment & Services',     6.0],
                    ['Insurance',     5.7],
                    ['Technology Hardware & Equipment',     5.4],
                    ['Consumer Services',     4.8],
                    ['Telecommunication Services',     4.7]                    
                ]
            }],

        colors: [
                    '#132f55',
                    '#4d6d8a',
                    '#7f95aa',
                    '#b2bfcb',
                    '#d1dae2',
                    '#e5eaef',
                    '#7f7f7f',
                    '#9e9e9e',
                    '#c9c9c9',
                    '#bcbdc0',
                    '#eeefef'
                      ]
});


    })
```

I ultimately want each slice in my pie to have incremental classes like:
 - slice-1
 - slice-2
 - slice-3

I've kind of got this working, but only when the chart resizes. I've tried to trigger my custom function in the load event, but nothing happens.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PbbR/262/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting colorSlices() as the load function worked just fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/6PbbR/274/

```
events: {
    redraw: function(event) {
        colorSlices();
    },
    load: colorSlices
}
```

You could also use this.point.x in the formatter to assign the class. I believe that would accomplish the same thing and alleviate the need for the events.

http://jsfiddle.net/6PbbR/280/

```
dataLabels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<span class="slice slice-'+(this.point.x+1)+'">' + 
        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,1,".",",") +' %</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kindly -- I had gotten to this point on my own, but it was driving me crazy that the effect wasn't working in IE8. I noticed I was missing "load: colorSlices" after my redraw event. Works perfect now!